# how to make selectable rules by zip code using html and css?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to ask a question how to make rules. I have 15 zip codes in New York City that I want to provide services for.
10001
10002
10003 etc.
How can I make it so that the selection is only for the current zip codes, the rest is rejected by the message: "we do not provide a service in this area?"
What would you recommend?

P.S. I'm not a coder, I'm building a WordPress site. I apologize if such questions are not asked here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom module with json file. JSON file will provide a list of zip code according to service. On Key change of input field You can search in JSON file and show the service. If not found you can show error message.